# Loopback 2 user types with the same userId

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm trying to get Loopback ready for my enterprise credentials using Passport, but I ran across something that maybe I'm doing wrong.

First off I have 2 different types of users: `participant` and `judge`.  Both of these models have a base of `User`.  I'm also using the memory database for now (eventually going to Mongo).

When I use the Passport example as a base, I have 3 other models defined:

- AccessToken
- userCredential
- userIdentity

All seems well when I'm able to login with `/participants/login` and get an accessToken in return.  I can also access `/participants/1` just fine (the ID of the logged in user).

Now with the same token I'm able to access `/judges/1` as well!!  This seems like a bit of a risk.  Now I know with mongo I probably won't get the same ID but that's besides the point (unless that's how it's supposed to work).

I did try and mess with the relations a bit, but found that if I make anything other than `foreignKey: 'userId'` in my relations, it'll fail to login.

Here's a snippet of the database:

```
"participant": {
  "1": "{\"createdDate\":\"2016-05-16T18:37:38.956Z\",\"name\":\"Participant Weed\",\"pin\":\"N0148094\",\"awaitingTeam\":true,\"videoSigned\":false,\"password\":\"$2a$10$NgIjGMEPUvmworA/C0vTiu2lA52SQqR6QXkOwh8IfJWVJBF8izDAu\",\"email\":\"t@lm.com\",\"id\":1}",
  "2": "{\"createdDate\":\"2016-05-16T18:37:38.956Z\",\"name\":\"Other Participant Weed\",\"pin\":\"N0148094\",\"awaitingTeam\":true,\"videoSigned\":false,\"password\":\"$2a$10$joljfw98Lf.3qdnIwf55nOEotAE3Zrcr97Fe5XKPE7j1PFy5O2h5.\",\"email\":\"t2@lm.com\",\"id\":2}"
},
"judge": {
  "1": "{\"createdDate\":\"2016-05-16T18:37:38.956Z\",\"name\":\"Judge Weed\",\"pin\":\"N0148094\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$ZiCmsGos3t7UYOpSK7s3BeAIIJ9lL0XjplOghOCXp1WTfh2MOr0vS\",\"email\":\"j@lm.com\",\"id\":1}"
},
```

Here what my relations look like for `participant`:

```
"relations": {
  "identities": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "userIdentity",
    "foreignKey": "userId"
  },
  "credentials": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "userCredential",
    "foreignKey": "userId"
  },
  "accessTokens": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "AccessToken",
    "foreignKey": "userId"
  }
},
```

Notice how I have to use `"userId"`.  These are exactly the same for `judge` as well.  I tried using `"participantId"` but kept getting `401` errors whenever I tried to log in with that.

Answer (score 2):

> I can also access /participants/1 just fine (the ID of the logged in user).
>
> Now with the same token I'm able to access /judges/1 as well!! This seems like a bit of a risk.

Did you setup access control on those endpoints ? Otherwise they are open by default.

Also, I would recommend against having two different models extending `User`, because it seems here you only need to setup [roles](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles) on a single model extending user. Doing so may reduce the amount of relations you will have to write, if there are interactions between `participant` and `judges`

Finally, IMO, you should be aware that the [loopback-component-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport) repository is not showing a lot of activity, 15 PR open at the moment, users reporting all sorts of bugs without much support behind it. It's a matter of choice but I would recommend to use directly `passportjs`. You will actually understand what is going on under the hood, and adding it to a loopback app is actually not that hard.

EDIT:

If you drop the loopback component, here is the strategy I employed to use OAuth and leverage loopback's access control system.

In the loopback component design, there are three models:

- UserIdentity : extends Persisted model, belongsTo MyUser
- UserCredential : same
- MyUser: extends User, hasMany UserIdentity, hasMany UserCredential

On the paper, it is nice to reduce coupling between the OAuth system and loopback `User` model.

However, in practice, I have found that this is a pain for setting up Access Control. Since `UserIdentity` is extending a `PersistedModel` and not `User`, this means that the `UserIdentity` model cannot be used for access control. For instance, impossible to have a `UserIdentity` be the $owner of something else.

It is possible to find the user from a given useridentity instance and use ACL with that. This could be interesting if a User could indeed have many UserIdentity. In practice, this doesn't seem to be useful, because how can you reliably identify a user from different UserIdentity ? (Basically, a same user can have a twitter account, a google account, etc. but what piece of information can be used to reliably link them together ? pretty much nothing)

So instead, the approach I used:

- MyUser : extends User, contains fields `provider` & `provider_id` to store the name of the oauth authentication provider, and the user id on this provider's platform
- UserCredentials : To store linked accounts credentials (You can **authenticate** using a google account, but maybe you also want to **link** a github and bitbucket account)

Then, when an user is authenticating to my platform through oauth, the first time, a `MyUser` instance is created. Since `MyUser` requires always an email and password, I generate both:

- email: `provider_id`@myapp.`provider`.com
- password: cryptographically strong random password

This way, the user is attributed an account with a unique email, but won't be able to log in "manually", only through OAuth

This is done in the serializeUser callback from passport (search for "serialize" in http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) that is called each time an authentication request is successful

Then, and for each time the user authenticates again through oauth, manually generate a Loopback token and pass it back in the response, this way the end user can be identified and you can leverage the entire LB ACL system.

Hope this helps, don't hesitate if you have feedback

Comment: This is good advice. Afaik the models in loopback are not designed like classes with subclasses in traditional OO structures that have true polymorphism. It is more of a way to extend models and storage backends than to have fully OO javascript. When you work with the `judge` model it is not truly aware that it is a child of User except that it was created that way and shares attributes/methods in one direction (up). Roles is the way to go for different types of users.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I've had to drop component-passport already since we are using SAML and ADFS within the organization.  Structure wise I created "routes_authenticated.js" in the `/boot` directory with all of that setup there.  Would I be able to still use `roles` and the like with standard passportjs?  How would a participant and judge have different attributes?

Comment: The short the answer is yes, I have edited my answer for the details